# After updating my Android Studio the emulator renders colors very badly

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, rendering

I just updated my Android Studio. I updated:

Android SDK Build-Tools 34-rc1

NDK (Side by side)

Android Emulator (to version 32.1.11)

Android SDK Platform-Tools (to version 34.0.0)

After updating those the emulator renders my flutter app very badly. Here is how the emulator renders my UI gradients after the update:

[After update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCIOG.png)

And here is how that looked before the update:

[Before update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeeqn.png)

So it seems that everything that uses opacity just looks horrible right now. How can I fix this without having to rollback, or is there just something wrong with the new emulator?

I tried to put

```
Future main() async {
    Paint.enableDithering = true;
    ...
```

to the app, which didn't help at all.

Answer (score 2):

I'm experiencing the same issue with the following versions:

- Android SDK Build-Tools 34-rc2
- Android SDK Platform-Tools 34.0.1
- Android Emulator 32.1.12

A temporary workaround I found is to change your emulator's OpenGL settings to the following and then restart the emulator:

- Renderer: SwiftShader
- API Level: Compatibility (OpenGL ES 1.1/2.0)

[Screenshot of Android Emulator OpenGL settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3rqAY.png)

Comment: Fixes the greenish color problem, thanks a lot